# how to check which files has been changed between two revisions in Mercurial / Tortoise Hg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, visual-diff

how to check which files has been changed between two revisions in Mercurial / Tortoise Hg?

I have tried visual diff of tortoiseHg, it do not highlight which specific files have been added, changed or unchanged and you have to click every file to get details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLI-version: `hg diff -r START -r END --stat`

Sample:

```
>hg diff -r 4 -r tip --stat
 404.php        |    4 ++--
 functions.php  |    2 +-
 readme.txt     |   28 +++++++++++++++++-----------
 screenshot.png |  Bin
 sidebar.php    |    2 +-
 style.css      |    4 ++--
 6 files changed, 23 insertions(+), 17 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have find out that in `Directory` menu of `Visual diff` of tortoiseHg you can select which files should be displayed.

So I navigated to `Directory` menu and **unselected** these:

- Show Identical files
- Show files only in A
- Show only files in B

And then I selected **Show different files**

[image]

Now visual diff is only showing files which are changed in 2 different revisions.